# Sketch the Solid of Integration

Tags: integration

We are given,

Sketch the solid of integration of the following integral and then evaluate it in the new order:

$$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{1-y} (xy) \, \mathrm{dxdy}, new order: dy dx$$

My first attempt involves changing the limits of integration and therefore the order of integration:

$$\int_{0}^{1-y}\int_{0}^{2} (xy) \, \mathrm{dydx}$$

I let $R$ be the region bounded by the lines

$$y = x - 1$$
$$y = 0$$
$$x = 2$$
$$x = 0$$

It is easy to see that 2-dimensionally we have a small region in the first quadrant bounded by

$$y = x - 1$$
$$y = 0$$
$$x = 2$$
$$x = 1$$

I am not fully competent at graphing 3D functions, but I think it may resemble a slant of some sort, by allowing

$$z = 1-y$$

Arriving with the following, may I proceed to integrate?

$$\int_{0}^{1-y}\int_{0}^{2} (xy) \, \mathrm{dydx}$$

Yields, $$2(1-y)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not simply change the order of the two integral. You need to consider the 2D area that you are integrating over. Sketch out the area given by: $y$ goes from $0$ to $2$ and $x$ goes from $0$ to $1-y$.

[image]

Note that the top half of it is actually going from $0$ to a negative number so it is backwards. We'll need to take that into account later.

Next lets look at the range of $x$ - it goes from $-1$ to $0$ then from $0$ to $1$. We need to treat them separately as $y$ is different in each half.

Next (for each half) look at how $y$ depends on $x$. For the positive half we have that $y$ goes from $0$ to $1-x$. For the negative half we have that $y$ goes from $1-x$ to $2$. The negative part was backwards so we'll put a negative sign in front of that (or we could reverse the limits).

So the equivalent integral (order reversed is):

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x} (xy)dydx-\int_{-1}^0\int_{1-x}^2(xy)dydx$$

**Now to evaluate it:**

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x} (xy)dydx-\int_{-1}^0\int_{1-x}^2(xy)dydx$$

$$=\int_0^1 \left(\frac{xy^2}{2}\right)_0^{1-x}dx-\int_{-1}^0 \left(\frac{xy^2}{2}\right)_{1-x}^2dx$$

$$=\int_0^1 \left(\frac{x(1-x)^2}{2}-\frac{x\cdot0^2}{2}\right)dx-\int_{-1}^0 \left(\frac{x\cdot2^2}{2}-\frac{x(1-x)^2}{2}\right)dx$$

$$=\int_0^1 \left(\frac{x-2x^2+x^3}{2}-\frac{x\cdot0^2}{2}\right)dx-\int_{-1}^0 \left(\frac{x\cdot2^2}{2}-\frac{x-2x^2+x^3}{2}\right)dx$$

$$=\left(\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{2x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{8}\right)_0^1-\left(x^2-\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{2x^3}{6}-\frac{x^4}{8}\right)_{-1}^0$$

$$=\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{2}{6}+\frac{1}{8}\right)-0-0+\left(1-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{2}{6}-\frac{1}{8}\right)$$

$$=\frac{1}{24}+\frac{7}{24}$$

$$=\frac13$$

Comment: I yielded 2 as my solution. Is this correct?

Comment: I got $\frac13$.

Comment: There is a zero area for the first integration of $x-x^2$ from 0 to 1?

Comment: The TI-89 tells me an Error: Dependent Limit.

Comment: I'll update my answer to include evaluating it.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate, as many others along this path.

Comment: I haven't used the TI-78 but I imagine it should be able to do it. Double check your syntax is correct. But make sure you can do it by hand first.

Comment: Check by WolframAlpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BIntegrate%5Bxy%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C1-y%7D%5D%2C%7By%2C0%2C2%7D%5D and http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BIntegrate%5Bxy%2C%7By%2C0%2C1-x%7D%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C1%7D%5D-Integrate%5BIntegrate%5Bxy%2C%7By%2C1-x%2C2%7D%5D%2C%7Bx%2C-1%2C0%7D%5D