# Volume of Solid in Triple Integrals of Cylindrical Coordinates

Tags: integration

We are asked:

Find the volume of the solid bounded above by the plane $z = y$ and below by the paraboloid $z = x^2 + y^2$ by using cylindrical coordinates.

Perhaps we can setup the integrand as follows

$$\iiint_E z dV$$

I have no idea how to include a graph using LaTeX, and I am not keen on searching for it, as it will lessen my 3D graphing capabilities (and likely confuse me). However, $z = y$ is just a slanted surface that does not cross over into the $x$ region and we know that $z = x^2 + y^2$ is a cylindrical cone. I think that we may evaluate the region E from the yz-plane.

We use cylindrical coordinates by allowing

$$x = r\cos\theta$$
$$y = r\sin\theta$$
$$z = z$$

How do I properly define the region $E$? My first presumption is

$$E = \{ (r,\theta, z) | 0 \leq \pi \leq 2\pi, 0 \leq r \leq 1, x^2 + y^2 \leq z \leq y\}$$

May I proceed to integrate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1560628/sketch-the-solid-of-integration) you need to think about the area you evaluating your integral over. Draw a sketch of the 2D surface which you need to integrate over. To do this you will need to find the area of intersection of the two curves then express that area as the bounds of your integral. Additionally your integral should only be a double integral of the form:

$$\int_{y_1}^{y^2}\int_{x_1}^{x_2} (z_1(x,y)-z_2(x,y)) dx dy$$
You can then convert it to a cylindrical form.

Here is a diagram to help you visualize it. While you can probably read off the limits of integration from my graph try and work them out algebraically (shouldn't be too hard) and that understanding will help you express your integral properly.

[image]

Edit: Same graph rotated to show side view more:

[image]

Comment: Yes, by reading off the graph I think that $x_1=-0.5$, $x_2=1.5$, $z_1=1$, $z_2=3$,$y_1=-1$,$y_2=1$. The expression within the inner integrand is $0$? Factoring out an $r^2$ for $z_1(x,y)$ and $z_2(x,y)$. Yielding $2$ as the solution - provided the limits of integration are correct and $z_1(x,y) = z_2(x,y) = x^2+y^2$

Comment: Based on this and your other question I think you've misunderstood a large portion of double integrals and need to reread your notes on the fundamentals of double integrals. I am reluctant to provide a worked solution to this question as I feel you won't learn from it.

Comment: To better understand double integrals think back to what a 1D integral is. It is the limit of the Reimann sum, i.e. adding up all those small rectangles and making the rectangles smaller. A double integral is the same idea applying a new dimension. It is the sum of lots of tall but thin rectangular prisms (or different shapes if not using rectangular coordinates) where the cross sectional area of the prism is getting smaller and smaller. The two integrals represent the two directions of the prisms which are getting smaller and smaller while the thing you are integrating represents the height.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your A+ work providing me with a in-depth detail of how these excises are approached.