# Using cylindrical to find the volume

Tags: calculus, integration

In the following textbook review question I have been asked to find the volume of the solid bounded above by the plane $ z = y $ and below by the paraboloid $ z = x^2 + y^2 $

looking for some help with this question

Comment: (I'm assuming you're also the user [javahelp](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/351881/javahelp) so you can ignore this if you're not) Just some advice: you're not going to get any better at these if you just keep asking here without trying to solve these yourself.  It's up to you of course, but if you care about learning this at all,  you should try to apply the techniques in the answers to the several nearly identical questions you've asked in the last day.

Comment: yes i will try and work through this myself but I get a little confused starting sometimes

Comment: see here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1560707/volume-of-solid-in-triple-integrals-of-cylindrical-coordinates?rq=1

Comment: no formal answer has been given, thanks for the link though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

1. Visualize/draw the region of which you are looking to find the volume of.
2. Characterize the region using (possibly variable) range for $x,y,z$. In your case, e.g., $x^2+y^2 \le z \le y$. Can you define correct ranges for $x,y$ to correspond to your region?
3. Integrate in those limits: $$V = \iiint 1 dxdydz$$