# Cylindrical Coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration

In the following example i am looking to find the volume of the solid bounded above by the plane $ z = y$ and below by the paraboloid $ z  = x^2 +y^2 $ by the method of cylindridical coordinates.

Looking to get some help on setting up the integration and evaluating it

Comment: You got hints for this question [from gt6989b](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1870624/using-cylindrical-to-find-the-volume).  What have you tried?  Have you done any work on this on your own?

Comment: i have tried to draw the picture and find points of intersection and the regionn needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The volume can be determined using the triple integral $$V = \iiint dV$$ once you determine the correct limits of integration.

Since your solid is bounded above by the plane and below by the paraboloid it lies above the two-dimensional region determined by $x^2 + y^2 \le y$ in the $x$-$y$ plane. In Cartesian coordinates you could complete the square to see this is precisely the disk $x^2 + (y-\frac 12)^2 \le \frac 14$. In polar coordinates the description is a bit simpler: $x^2 + y^2 \le y$ converts to $r^2 \le r \sin \theta$ so that the region is given by $r \le \sin \theta$, with $0 \le \theta \le \pi$.

Thus appropriate limits of integration are $0 \le \theta \le \pi$, $0 \le r \le \sin \theta$, and $r^2 \le z \le r \sin \theta$. This leads to $$V = \int_0^\pi \int_0^{\sin \theta} \int_{r^2}^{r \sin \theta}dz \, r drd\theta.$$

Comment: okay from here i just integrate?

Comment: so the first integration would just be z then i would have to plug in r^2 - rsintheta